# Did John von Neumann solve any unsolved problem in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, biographical-details, von-neumann

I have searched and examined legendary stories of the problem-solving skills of von Neumann in mathematics.

1. With [George Polya](https://www.quora.com/What-theorem-did-John-von-Neumann-prove-during-George-Polyas-lecture)
2. With [Dantzig](https://mosstuff.quora.com/The-most-complete-version-of-the-Dantzig-meets-von-Neumann-anecdote-I-ve-seen)

Maybe there are other stories showing that he is a great problem-solver, but I think these two are well-known.

I know that he wrote many papers in pure mathematics (mostly developing new concepts), but with his talented problem-solving skills, didn't he write any paper on solving unsolved problems in mathematics? Maybe I haven't searched enough?

Just because he was not interested in publishing a paper on that subject?

Or, even for him, it is not easy solving problems that are worthy of publishing. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking whether von Neumann **solved** any (previously) unsolved problem in math?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, maybe my writing was vague...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John von Neumann (partially) solved [Hilbert's fifth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem).

Plus: he is one of those that contributed to solving [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) by building the axioms of maths.

Answer (score 5):

One guess: There was a question from physics on how to formulate quantum mechanics.  Von Neumann proposed doing it using operators on Hilbert space. (1927-1929)

Comment: Which is part of Hilbert's sixth problem.